# Photoshop saving for png result unexpected

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I have multiple layers with particular parts of products with `Multiply` applied and different `opacity` but when I try to save the image in `png` **with** transparency it seems like those layers which I used for `Multiply` don't work else without transparency result is same as expected.

This is what I am expecting and as it looks in photoshop

**Expected Result:** [image]

But when I save them transparent a white shadow gets added near product *(I have added a background so that you can easily see the white artifact getting automatically added to the bottom right of image and above middle two boxes)

**Unexpected Result:** [image]

Comment: This is my psd file: http://www.mediafire.com/?5dxd7q7efna4qq6

Comment: This could easily just be a problem with photoshop rendering your work. When you're working on an image inside of photoshop it doensn't _really_ show you what your image looks like, it's not 100% accurate. My thought is that your image is just a bit messy, and if you clean it up, photoshop should save it just fine.

Answer (score 3):

what i think this is not a PNG issue what you are doing is your both object are not similar to each other i checked your PSD and i slightly lift your top layer and erase all object content similar to your top layer,  the output is ready.

8-bit png's don't do transparency properly.  Save them as 32-bit and see.

Your Issue :

[image: Issue]

My Output :
[image: desired output]

Please let me know if you are not satisfied with this...

Answer (score 3):

There should be no reason to save the image with transparency if you are including the background in the image. Saving a PNG with transparency means it will preserve the alpha channel parts of the image, and show through whatever you place the PNG on.

If you are intending to save the image without a background, keep in mind that blend modes such as Multiply or Screen won't have the desired effect, since they have nothing to blend with in the file (blend modes can't anticipate what background you place the exported PNG on).

That said, the white artifacts are present in your PSD file. I suggest cleaning up the edges more in order to minimize the jaggy white bits. Try the Refine Edge button.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet this is due to your mask. Your psd shows pretty much a white halo around your objects which when flattened will get worse.

After some quick tests (in Pixelmator), saving the image in that green background did produce some white borders, but using a stark red, seemed to blend much nicer. Seems that green (after flattening) is producing a tougher contrast. Also having no color behind there (only transparency) worked just fine as well.

This is hardly a definitive answer but it may be a combo of your ask quality and bg color.

Answer (score 1):

Image formats with alpha channel support only simple blending, and don't support blending modes like "Multiply".

For best approximation merge all your layers into one (to make Photoshop apply multiply where possible) and use normal blending mode for the only remaining layer. This will be saved accurately in true-color PNG.